# Ubuntu 20.04 Unity Question

Tags: unity, 20.04

So I want to install Ubuntu and I love Unity.Well Ubuntu 16.04 is kinda old so I want to go with 20.04 . if I install ubuntu then add from terminal Unity and remove GNOME, will I have any problems with future updates? I'm not planning to move to another version since a new LTS will come out.

Comment: You can try this remix which has Unity installed out of the box. It is actively developed, and has a telegram support group. It is not an official flavour of Ubuntu, though. https://ubuntuunity.org/

Answer (score 0):

In as far as Unity will continue to be maintained and supported for future Ubuntu versions, and in as far as you correctly add and remove software using the APT system, then no, you will not have problems with future updates.